# How to adjust the width of a DIV per height using CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

I have a wrapper div with a `max-width` of `1000px` and `max-height` of `650px`.

I want to dynamically adjust the width and height of this wrapper while maintaining its aspect ratio. If the browser window is re-sized to reduce the width, the height should be adjusted. If the height is reduced, the width should be adjusted accordingly.

I am using HTML5 and CSS3. This is an attempt to create a responsive layout which works on desktop and mobile devices.

Comment: You can try specifying widths in percentages (%) instead of pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using CSS3 you can make use of [the `vmin` or `vmax` units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths). 1 `vmin` is equivalent to 1/100 the size of whichever is smallest out of height or width, whereas 1 `vmax` is equal to 1/100 the size of the larger value. If a user's screen had a resolution of 1000x800px, `100vmin` would be equal to 800px and `100vmax` would be equal to 1000px, as the height here is the smaller unit and the width is the larger unit.

In your case you can make use of it like this:

```css
div {
    height: 65vmin;
    width: 100vmin;
}
```

Or:

```css
div {
    height: 65vmax;
    width: 100vmax;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/D8X6n/).

Note that you'll have to adjust these values yourself. `100vmin` here will set the width to full size of the screen's height or width (whichever is smallest), and this may not be the desired effect.

There are a couple of browser issues with this approach, unfortunately. As they are new units, support is not perfect. Some browsers will not resize the container until the page is reloaded.

Comment: Thanks James! Really promising solution. Is this supported on IE9? My product needs to run on IE 9 and above on desktops as well as mobile devices.

Comment: @user3214481 if you see the link xpy posted in his comment above yours , IE9 has partial support for this. The only popular up-to-date mobile browser which doesn't support this is Opera Mini.

Comment: Oops! missed it earlier. Thanks for pointing out. Really appreciate your help James and xpy!

Answer (score 1):

Represent width and height using `%` 
  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jeyashri/QzVF9/807/)**

Try this,

**HTML:**

```
<div><p>content</p></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 35%;
  padding: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

p {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Using Jquery,

**jQuery Code:**

```
var width = $('#widthHeight').width();
$('#widthHeight').css('height', width);
```

**[jqueryDEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jeyashri/QzVF9/811/)**

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I have tried this. This solution adjusts the height of the div when the width is adjusted. However, my problem is bit more complex. I need to adjust the width is height is reduced and height if width reduced. Let me know if more clarification is required.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy to adjust height to width.

Since `padding` percentages are relative to parent's `width` (even for the height yes) you can do something like this:

`.smth {
    height: 0;
    padding: 100% 0 0 0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/LSK2j/1/)**

```
div
{
    width: 153.8vh; /* 100/65 * 100 */
    height: 65vw; /* 100/1.538 = 65 */
    background: pink;
    max-height: 650px;
    max-width: 1000px; 
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0; /* vertical center */
    left:0;right:0; /* horizontal center */
}
```

Comment: It seems to work just fine while adjusting the width/height proportionately. However, it doesn't work if width or height is adjusted independently.